# How to import class (.js file) in a .vue file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, export

I have a class that is called Authenthicator and it is in the file Authenticator.js. I want to use its functions in my vue application, specificaly in the file Login.vue.

How can I export the class Authenticator and import it in Login.vue?

I get these errors:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at patch (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:31)
    at patch (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:96)
    at Object.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:88)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:348)
    at Object../node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js (chunk-vendors.js:10849)
    at **webpack_require** (app.js:785)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at Object.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/gulp-sourcemaps/src/init/index.internals.js:9)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/gulp-sourcemaps/src/init/index.internals.js:124)
    at Object../node_modules/gulp-sourcemaps/src/init/index.internals.js (chunk-vendors.js:11038)

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_IO_SUSPENDED

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: None of this is working in my vue application...

Comment: You have to be more specific than "None of this is working". This most definitely *does* work when done correctly.

Comment: maybe provide your code?

Answer (score 1):

```
 export default class Authenticator {
    // ...
 }
```

And import in file:

```
  import Authenticator from "path/to/file/authenticator.js
  var Auth = new Authenticator ();
```

Comment: I tried that, but the thing is that my vue application stops showing when I do that and when I remove those lines, its working again..

Comment: Could you please press F12 and tell us the error in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty hard to help without your code, but here's a basic example:

Authenticator.js

```
'use strict';

class Authenticator {
    // ...
};

module.exports.Authenticator = Authenticator;
```

Login.vue

```
<script>
import Authenticator from 'path/to/Authenticator.js';

const AuthenticatorInstance = new Authenticator;

// use it...

</script>
```

Comment: I tried that, but the thing is that my vue application stops showing when I do that and when I remove those lines, its working again..

Comment: I don't get errors, its just showing nothing (but building successfull)

Answer (score 0):

Authenticator.js

```
class Authenticator {
    //
    };

export default new Authenticator;
```

Login.vue

```
<script>
import Authenticator from 'path/Authenticator';
</script>
```